# Reading config file in C using libconfig

Tags: c, configuration-files, libconfig

I defined a structure for options in my config file and a pointer to this structure in "config.h" file and I read config file using libconfig and set values in function get_config() that is defined in file "config.c". In main function I initialize pointer to structure and call get_config() function. libconfig works well and prints values of structure's fields correctly but when I print same fields in main functions their values are incorrect!

"config.h"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libconfig.h>

typedef struct
{
    int buffer_size;
    const char * DBusername;
    const char * DBpassword;
}conf;

conf *config;

int get_config();
```

"config.c"

```
#include "config.h"


int get_config()
{
    config_t cfg;
    config_setting_t *setting;

    config_init(&cfg);

    /* Read the file. If there is an error, report it and exit. */
    if(! config_read_file(&cfg, "config.cfg"))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d - %s\n", config_error_file(&cfg),
            config_error_line(&cfg), config_error_text(&cfg));
        config_destroy(&cfg);
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(config_lookup_int(&cfg, "buffersize", &config->buffer_size))
        printf("buffersize: %d\n\n", config->buffer_size);
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "No 'buffersize' setting in configuration file.\n");

    if(config_lookup_string(&cfg, "DBusername", &config->DBusername))
        printf("DBusername: %s\n\n", config->DBusername);
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "No 'DBusername' setting in configuration file.\n");

    if(config_lookup_string(&cfg, "DBpassword", &config->DBpassword))
        printf("DBpassword: %s\n\n", config->DBpassword);
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "No 'DBpassword' setting in configuration file.\n");

    config_destroy(&cfg);

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```

"store.c"

```
int main(){
    config = (conf*) malloc(sizeof(conf));
    if(get_config() == EXIT_FAILURE)
        return 0;

    printf("\n%s", config->DBusername);
    printf("\n%s", config->DBpassword);
    printf("\n%d", config->buffer_size);
}
```

Comment: You should include either the actual code or a **[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)**.

Comment: Its likely because the scope (visibilty)of the structure is not provided to the file the `main()` function resides in.  Include the .h where the struct is defined, and make sure an instantiation of that struct either has global scope, or create an instantiation inside `main()` (which would be of no value, but could be used)

Comment: "To link with the library, specify ‘-lconfig’ as an argument to the linker." How can you do this for makefile?

Comment: @ZuzooVn, in Makefile.am file (Because of comment limit it's not possible to include complete Makefile.am): ... ... LIBS = -lconfig $(MYSQL) ... install-data-local: $(INSTALL) srv_store.conf $(DESTDIR)$(CONFIGDIR)/srv_store.conf.default if test ! -f $(DESTDIR)$(CONFIGDIR)/srv_store.conf; then $(INSTALL) srv_store.conf $(DESTDIR)$(CONFIGDIR)/srv_store.conf; fi EXTRA_DIST= struct.h config.h db.h file.h config.cfg $(MYSQL) $(LIBS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because of defining char* in structure. I changed the char* to char[] and the problem is solved! :)

Answer (score 0):

*I defined a structure for options in my config file and a pointer to this structure in "config.h" file...*

That statement makes me wonder what a *config file* is.  i.e. is it a .c, or a .h?  And what is the visibility to it for other files?

Your issue is likely because the scope (visibilty) of the structure is not provided to the file in which the `main()` function resides. `#include` the .h where the struct is defined, and make sure an instantiation of that struct either has global scope, or create an instantiation inside main()

This configuration of files will provide visibility to to main of a struct defined in the .h:

in somefile.h:

```
typedef struct 
{
  int membername;
} A_STRUCT;

extern A_STRUCT a
```

;

in someotherFile.c

```
#include "somefile.h"

A_STRUCT a = {3};  //global copy of the struct, with assignment

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d", a.membername);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please see my code. The main problem is that structure's fields are set in another function! The "config" pointer is visible to main.